# JavaFx Set Label Text on Scene Open

Tags: java, javafx

I have an FXML file with an empty Label named **welcomeText**.
It's the main Scene of my program and I would like to set the label text to something like that: ***Hello "username"*** when I start the program on Windows or Linux.

```
public class MainAdminController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label welcomeText;
final String username = System.getProperty("user.name");

@FXML
private void SetWelcome() {
welcomeText.setText("Hello " +username);
 }
}
```

But it isn't show anything. Any idea how can I set the Label properly when I open the scene? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you just need to do this in the `initialize()` method? Otherwise, you would need to explicitly call `setWelcome()` from somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SetWelcome` method is superfluous.

Define an `initialize()` method for your controller and it will automatically be invoked when the FXMLLoader loads a new document linked to the controller.

```
public void initialize() {
    welcomeText.setText("Hello " +username);
}
```